# How to make PHP undefined constants notice an error

Tags: php, constants

I just spent hours trying to debug an out of memory error caused by the following code:

```
for ($i = 1; i <= 4; $i++) {
  $allowed[] = $type.'_'.$i;
}
```

Which PHP kindly mangles into:

```
for ($i = 1; 'i' <= 4; $i++) {
  $allowed[] = $type.'_'.$i;
}
```

This causes an endless loop, which eventually leads to an out of memory error due to appending to the array. PHP will generate a notice level error, and I could change my error reporting level to show these but I am working on a third party application which has a tendency to generate enough of these that this isn't really a viable solution.

Is there any way to trap these really simple bugs? Ironically, if you do something like `constant('i')` and explicitly ask for the value it will generate a warning rather than a notice, and this behaviour would be ideal.

Comment: A modern IDE should show you such mistakes

Comment: Matthew php already shows that error as a notice :d

Comment: @KingCrunch it does, but having an error happen when I miss something helps actually debug it. If I miss something in my IDE then try to run the page and it says "Oh, you did something stupid in this file on this line" and doesn't try to run it, then I'll go to that line and file and then I'll see the problem.

Comment: @KingCrunch it also doesn't help me any if I'm looking at something that someone else has done and trying to figure out what's broken.

Comment: @yes123: It also shows a lot of other 'error's as notices. This in particular really shouldn't be a notice, it's at best a warning, but really should be an error, in my opinion at least.

Comment: I dont get what you mean.. Php cleary shows that error as a notice. Debug at that point is easy

Comment: @yes123 from my question: "PHP will generate a notice level error, and I could change my error reporting level to show these but I am working on a third party application which has a tendency to spit out a lot of these so that isn't really a viable solution." Sorting out which notices are noise, and which actually matter takes time too. Better that this actually a warning such as what `constant()` produces.

Comment: @KingCrunch in particular, I wasn't even looking at this piece of code till I ran the site through a profiler. I figured the memory error was a side effect of a larger error, and that the piece of code it was dying on was merely coincidence as the larger code it is part of does image manipulation and has been known to cause memory errors before (though, testing with ~40kb files it shouldn't have).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could create a custom error function then filter out the most common errors and only report the less common ones. Then up the error reporting level in PHP. E.g.

```
function customError($error_no, $error_message, $error_file, $error_line, $error_context) {
    $common_errors = Array('File not found', 'Another made up error', 'Its late');
    if (! in_array($error_message, $common_errors)) {
        // throw exception, log to file, or other action
    }
}

set_error_handler("customError");
```

You could also filter errors like so:

- Filter out all errors unless they are
  in a file of interest by testing
  `$error_file` against an array of
  files you maintain
- Even better (not on a production
  server) fetch the last_modified
  date/time of `$error_file` with
  `filemtime()` and report the error if
  it was changed within the last 10
  minutes. This helps you debug code as
  you write it
- Or if it's within a framework which
  yours sounds like it is, break apart
  the path of `$error_file` and test if
  it's in your module/view/controller
  files, as opposed to core framework
  files

Comment: Added more filtering options. The last might be best as you're working in a framework

Answer (score 1):

In PHP 7.2 this notice has been changed to a warning.

In PHP 8.0 it will be an error.